# vb form not updating if new object added, original form keeps loading

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

As the title suggest when I make edits to program either by dragging object on form or by adding code and then debugging nothing happens. The 1st version of the form keeps on executing any changes are ignored,what am I missing here?

Comment: try a Clean, Rebuild

Comment: @bansi as in start over? or is there an option on the GUI where I can execute a rebuild? Thanxs

Comment: I am not suggesting to start over. You can find Clean and Rebuild in the Build menu of Visual studio. Also it is a good idea to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in your project directory forcing VS to recompile everything

Comment: @Bansi got it thank you sooooooo much, you wont believe me but I struggled for 2 hours trying to fix it